# Why does code path not returning value error thrown while all for loops are proper?

Tags: c#

**not all code paths return a value error is thrown while executing it.please help us to resolve it at the earliest.
There seems to be some code path that is not returning any value.
can someone please help to fix it up?
There are many for loops in the code. i am not able to figure which one is causing this issue.**

using System;

using System.Collections.Generic;

using System.IO;

using System.Linq;

using System.Text;

using System.Threading.Tasks;

//namespace ConsoleApp7

//{

class Solution

{

```
static bool CheckElementSymbol(string elementName, string symbol)

{



    symbol = symbol.ToLower();



    int symbol_length = symbol.Length;



    int numberofchars = 0;

    int firstletter = 0;

    bool firstcharfound = false;

    bool secondcharfound = false;

    //bool symbolfound = false;

    //int symbolpresent = 0;

    int secondcharmatch = 0;



    if (symbol_length == 2)

    {



        foreach (char sym in symbol)

        {

            numberofchars = numberofchars + 1;



            var firstcharmatch = new List<int>();

            //int index = 0;

            int sourcelength = elementName.Length;



            if (numberofchars == 1)



            {

                for (int index = 0; index < sourcelength; index++)

                {



                    int matchfound1stchar = elementName.IndexOf(sym, index, 1);

                    if (matchfound1stchar != -1)



                    {

                        firstletter = 1;

                        firstcharmatch.Add(matchfound1stchar + 1);

                    }







                }







                if (firstletter == 1)



                {

                    firstcharfound = true;



                }



                else



                {

                    firstcharfound = false;

                }

            }



            //int matchingchar = elementName



            if (numberofchars == 2)

            {

                secondcharmatch = elementName.LastIndexOf(elementName, sym);



                //yield return index;



                if (secondcharmatch != -1)



                {

                    secondcharfound = true;

                    secondcharmatch = secondcharmatch + 1;

                }



                else

                { secondcharfound = false; }



            }



            //int matchingchar = elementName



            if (secondcharfound == true && firstcharfound == true)

            {



                foreach (int value in firstcharmatch)

                {

                    if (secondcharmatch > value)

                    {

                        //symbolfound = true;

                        //return symbolfound;

                        return true;

                    }





                        return false;







                }

            }



            else

            {

                return false;

            }







        }

    }



    else

    {

        return false;

    }



}



    static void Main(string[] args)

    {

        TextWriter textWriter = new StreamWriter(@System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("OUTPUT_PATH"), true);



        string elementName = Console.ReadLine();



        string symbol = Console.ReadLine();



        bool res = CheckElementSymbol(elementName, symbol);



        textWriter.WriteLine((res ? 1 : 0));



        textWriter.Flush();

        textWriter.Close();

    }



}
```

//}

Comment: "_please help us to resolve it at the earliest._" No. People here will help you at **their** convenience, if and when **they** like. People volunteer their time here, and urging them to solve your problems more quickly and in favor of questions/problems of other people could be perceived as rude/inconsiderate. (no, i did not take offence, so no need to worry about me ;-) ) Also, it doesn't help people trying to engage with your problem if you format your code in your question very poorly and spread it out by inserting hundreds of empty lines throughout your code...

Comment: Advice: Try to create small helper methods instead of nesting foreach in complex if/else structure. Simple code is a bit harder to write but is much better for maintenance and testing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem. If the string has no characters then it should return false

```
if (symbol_length == 2)
    {

        foreach (char sym in symbol)(...)//this code is irrelevant.
        return false; //here is the solution, if there are no characters in the string, then return false .
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
```

Next time make your code more easily read and only show the relevant parts.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, please post only relevant and minimal code in your question in order to get quick response.

For your query, you need to understand that the compiler error you are getting is

> error CS0161: 'Solution.CheckElementSymbol(string, string)': not all
>   code paths return a value

This error is because all your return statements are inside either IF or ELSE statements.
The error would get fixed if you add a return statement at the end of `CheckElementSymbol` method.

```
return false;
```

Hope this helps.